# How to get my School's Wifi CA Certificate on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, certificate

I am trying to connect to my School Wifi on Ubuntu.

The network specializations are:

I can't get the network specifications right now. But I do know it uses WPA-Enterprise, PEAP, MSCHAPv2

I need to get a CA certificate am I able to copy the certificate from my windows machine? And if so, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Since it uses WPA-Enterprise, you'll need to contact your school for help; this requires they supply the file.

Comment: So there is not way, not even by looking in `certmgr.msc`?